# Blender 2.92 Python Use of IntProperties crashes addon

Tags: python, blender

I am, a total newbie to this, trying my first addon that has a properties panel with three Int variables that I can modify.

Changing these values crashes blender almost all the time.

I suppose that it would not be cool to upload here the 516 lines of the addon so that somebody could look at it!

Is there a way to save the latest messages from the console when blender crashes?

I am totally clueless as to what I can do to debug that one!

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can start Blender from console. When it crashes the error will be in this console.

Comment: How do I do that!

Comment: Ok, I've done my homework and I found out how to do run blender from the command prompt so that the console stays open when it crashes, and there I could see that upon a crash, blender saves a crash file.

And that is again the end of the road for me because I have no clue as to how to interpret what is in that file, any ideas...

Comment: What is the error output now? Also could you modify your 516 lines to the bare minimum which cause the error?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that there were answers (I do not mean to be impolite vis a vis you nice folks who use time  on my problems!)

I master a little bit more running blender from the command line, and I have found the error message location, at the end.

Thank you a lot for the imput...